# Convert 1-dimensional array with n items, into n-dimensional array

Tags: php

How to convert this:

```
$arr = array('item1','item2','item3','item4','...');
```

to this:

```
$arr2['item1']['item2']['item3']['item4']['...'] = $something;
```

Comment: What is `$something`? The last value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$arr2 = $something;
foreach (array_reverse($arr) as $key) {
    $arr2 = array($key => $arr2);
}
```

Comment: Not working. Result is:
Array ( [item1] => Array ( [item2] => Array ( [item3] => Array ( [item4] => Array ( [...] => 'alabala') ) ) ) )

Comment: Yes...? That's what you want.

Comment: Sorry it's my fault. Thanks a lot.